# What is the relationship between the size of a particle and its velocity relative to a fixed frame of reference?

Tags: special-relativity, particle-physics, mass, speed-of-light, perception

I know photons travel at the speed of light. How does the size of a particle determine its maximum velocity? What is the speed of electrons, quarks and other particles? Is there a scale in from the smallest particle's maximum velocity to the largest?  Can neutrinos and tachyons exist and or travel faster than light?

Comment: Whatever particle you want. How much money do you have?

Comment: If they have same energy at an instant, their speed is inversely proportional to their mass/ energy. So, you just have to compare their mass. I think , we don't currently know mass of preons.Its under huge controversy.

Comment: Te recent edits seem to substantially changing the meaning of the question.

Comment: @dmckee I tried not to refine it so much where the answers were not viable.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you pay careful attention you'll notice *that* cosmic ray passing the earth just now. You are moving at 99.999%$c$ relative that particle. In fact the whole planet is doing so. From which we conclude that you don't even need a lot of money to make people go close to $c$, you just need the appropriate frame of reference.

Now, I know perfectly well that didn't answer the question you intended, but I gave that answer for a reason: there is nothing magic or special about any speed *other* than $c$. The physics of massive objects simply doesn't care about absolute motion. Ever. At all.

And that means that there is no list of "Things that can go really fast but can't go at $c$". Everything is on one of two lists: "Things that only go at $c$" and "Things that can't go at $c$".

Comment: They say neutrinos can go faster than c?

Comment: Unfortunately that was due to a calibration/technical error in the experiment, as opposed to a real life physical effect. The experiment was repeated and was found that neutrinos do in fact travel at a speed below that of the speed of light.

Answer (score 1):

There is only one real fundamental speed limit, $c$. Historically, we first discovered it in the context of light, so we call it the speed of light. In reality, it has a little bit deeper significance--it turns out all massless particles travel at $c$ and only at $c$, at least in vacuum.

A massive particle can theoretically travel at any speed less than $c$, and in fact different people will disagree at what speed it is going depending on how fast they're traveling next to it. (In comparison, light looks like it's going at $c$ to everyone.)

EDIT: To directly address the question: one particle which regularly travels close to the speed of light--such that it was a big debate whether or not they had mass at all--is the neutrino, which is so light that even a little bit of energy gets it nearly to light speed.